# How to restore a deleted file with certain extension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to if there is a way ( method ) I can import from a library or a module to let me restore ( recover ) a deleted files with certain extension using python 3.x because I am writing a program depending on this ...

Selecting A Partian

```
import os

class Storage:
    def select(self):
        letter = input("Press Storage Letter Name\n")
        partition_name = os.startfile(format(letter.upper() + ':'))
        print(partition_name)

card = Storage()
card.select()

#Scan Photo

import os

class Photo:
    def scan(self):
        confirm = input("Confirm Letter Name\n")
        path = format(confirm.upper() + ':')
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for f in files:
                if f.endswith('.mp4'):
                    print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t believe it is quite that simple.

There are a number of issues:

1. Filesystem on media
2. Media type (SSD vs HDD)
3. If SSD is trim enabled?
4. Did erase to a trash can or console delete?
5. Is the media mounted as read only? (To preserve from further data loss with accidental overwriting)